# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

У меня есть файл `app.jsx`, в который импортируется `createBrowserHistory`, есть компонент `Header` и файл с логикой этого компонента `HeaderContainer`, при клике на кнопку выдает `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. Понимаю, что по какой-то причине `history` из `app.jsx` не доходит до файла `HeaderContainer`, но не могу найти ошибку. Буду рад любой помощи.

Файл `app.jsx`

```
import React from "react";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import ROUTES from './routes';

import Bets from '../pages/bets';
import HeaderContainer from "../common/components/header/HeaderContainer/HeaderContainer";

import './app.scss';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router history={history}>
        <HeaderContainer />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path={ROUTES.ALL_BETS} component={Bets}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Файл `Header`

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import NavBar from '../../navBar';
import Button from '../../buttons/mainButton';
import SecondaryButton from "../../buttons/secondaryButton";
import DropDownList from "../../dropDownList";
import Icon from "../../icon";

import logo from '../../../../assets/icons/logo.svg';

import './header.scss';

export default function Header(props) {

  const {
    className,
    onRegistration
  } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classnames('header', className)}>
      <div className="header__logo">
        <NavLink to="/">
          <Icon className="header__logo-image" glyph={logo.id} viewBox={logo.viewBox} width="95" />
        </NavLink>
      </div>
      <div>
        <NavBar />
      </div>
      <div>
        <DropDownList />
        <Button caption="Sign in" />
        <SecondaryButton caption="Sign up" onClick={onRegistration} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Header.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string
}

Header.defaultProps = {
  className: undefined
}
```

Файл `HeaderContainer`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ROUTES from '../../../../app/routes';

import Header from '../HeaderComponent/Header';

export default class HeaderContainer extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};

    this.redirectRegistration = this.redirectRegistration.bind(this);
  }

  redirectRegistration(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { history } = this.props;

    history.push('/');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Header
        onRegistration={this.redirectRegistration}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавить в HeaderContainer

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class HeaderContainer ....

...

export default withRouter(HeaderContainer)
```

или с хуками:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

....

let history = useHistory();
```